# iOS app is rejected because of user buy subscription without IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, subscription

I build a tool app on iOS platform. I want create three level for users. basic, pro and premium. each level provide different functions. So user need pay for pro and premium subscription plan. the difference between level is pro user can create more document than basic user.

The thing is I don't want use IAP, I don't want apple share the 30% revenue, so I created a website to let user pay the subscription through web. 
I got the app approved 3 times before, without any rejection.
but recently, Apple review team reject my app with follow info

> From Apple
>   11.13 - Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>   11.13 Details
>
> We noticed that your app provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.

I am very sure that I didn't have any button or link inside of app to navigate user to website for payment. 
My app do grab the subscription level from website by API to restrict user function by level. I am not very sure if this is not allowed by apple.
I check apple review guideline again and find

> 11.14 Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the App, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content. Apple will only receive a portion of revenues for content purchased inside the App

Kindle and dropbox are following 11.14. they removed IAP from app and let user buy content from website. I can tell they are following 11.14. so apple approve that.

But 11.14 only works for magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage. while I am not sure whether my app belongs one of them. But my app is very similar with Evernote. Evernote provide payment both on website and IAP.

So my question is If Evernote remove IAP from app and only let user buy from website. will apple reject that? If not, then my app should not be rejected.

Comment: in pokerstars app you click the buy button and pay in webview, it is interesting

Comment: Try resubmitting, sometimes different people reviewing your app have different opinions or follow the guidelines more strict than others.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey  thanks for your reply. I knew it. I have to know whether it is allowed or not. I can not expect a the app is reviewed by an unstrict reviewer

Comment: Its not. Im suprised this is the first time your app was rejected. If apple can find anyway to force you to cut them a check, they will.

Comment: @MatthewLawrenceBailey  but Evernote works. I know Evernote use IAP, but if I buy a pro from website, I can refresh the app to be pro. even not using IAP, I can use pro permission on app.

Comment: In my honest opinion. Big name apps probably strike legal deals. Can you imagine what the app store would be like if there was no spotify or facebook because they refused to pay apple a 30% cut. Or only offered those big apps on android? Apple would lose a lot of customers.

Comment: By the looks of it if you got it so that the people can purchase goods and services outside the app, but use them inside. You'd be good. But if they want to pay through the app you have to go through apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming within the scope defined in the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @DanCornilescu Where should I put this question in stack overflow?

Comment: @DanCornilescu this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat: ACK. That's why there was a maybe in there :)

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately this is a question that you should be asking Apple. Different reviews catch different things. Although you may not have a button to send people to your website to pay for the subscription, it kind of sounds like the only purpose of the website is to buy a subscription for the app (if i'm wrong feel free to correct me). If thats the case i can completely understand the rejection. Apple wants purchases made for subscriptions for the app to be made in the app which means going through Apple and dealing with them taking %30. If you make a website with the sole purpose of bypassing Apples guidelines then they are going to notice eventually.

Also the difference between your app and Evernote from the sounds of it, is that Evernote has other platforms that the subscription relates too. The app just happens to be another place the user can benefit from the subscription.

At the end of the day i would mostly recommend that you think about the user experience first. I get not wanting to shave off %30, but you may end up gaining more subscriptions by having IAP in your app and giving away the %30 then by not having an in app subscription mechanism at all.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your reply.  The website is kind of a web admin console, it provide very important function to support app. And it provide subscription function.  On website, there is same function provided same as app. so I can not force my users to use IAP to pay for website function.

Comment: @user418751 how you solve this  issue