# Does Apple allows Purchase of content from web app?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have 2 scenarios for my iOS app.

1. The user can purchase valid coupon code from my shopping cart website and they can user coupon code to access the application.
2. The user can download the app from app store and on Login Screen we have webpage link where the user will be navigated to my website and purchase coupon code to access the app.

Do Apple have any restriction to allow the user to purchase coupon code out side the apple environment?

Comment: My app recently get rejected as i were redirecting user to website for Payment. So, answer without any doubt, your app will also get rejected.  Even if you are redirecting user for "SignUp" to website, that is also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple give you some [Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#goods-and-services) that you have to follow.

> Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

So I don’t think that your scenarios will be possible.

**Edit :**
[iOS app is rejected because of user buy subscription without IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757774/ios-app-is-rejected-because-of-user-buy-subscription-without-iap)

> > From Apple 11.13 - Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected 11.13 Details